# load testing results now serves lesser users

Tags: elasticsearch, jmeter, threadgroup

I was testing website with 30 users/second and it was working fine. But now it is not even serving 25 users/second. The website is a search engine kind of site. In between these two tests of 30 users/second and 25 users/seconds, we have started the crawler to get some sites crawled and then again stopped it before the load testing. 30 users/second was working fine before crawler turned on. Elastic search is used as DB for the website and it went down saying no nodes available.

I've used standard thread group. Below is the configuration.
Total Samples: 250
Ramp up (sec) : 10
Loop count : 1

When I checked the results in table, it shows all green signal but when we hit the site, it gives nonodesavailable exception

Comment: We really need more informations about your setup and configuration of the cluster and indices. Have there been a exception in the application/cluster logs? How is your connection to the cluster set up?

Comment: Can you please upload jmx file which you use?

Comment: I cannot upload the jmx file but adding some extra information regarding the issue.